# Limit to 1 on hasMany-relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many

I have two models that are related to each other. One model contains users, and the other contains all courses and related timestamp of class start. Now the "related key" between them are the 'user_id' which are in both tables. I manage to get out data when having:

```
return $this->hasMany(ClassInfo::class,'user_id','user_id');
```

This works just fine. However, since I use the model in a with clause I need to the only one of the classes that starts a given time if start time crashes with another course for the user. I have tried with both:

```
return $this->hasMany(ClassInfo::class,'user_id','user_id')->take(1);
return $this->hasMany(ClassInfo::class,'user_id','user_id')->limit(1);
```

But both just give me empty collections, I don't see why that happends?
Is there any way that I can make it return for example the one with the biggest id value from the Class table (id is auto incremental for each course registered on a user).

Thanks for any tips and guidance!

Comment: Are you using the relationship with eager loading?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, but I might found a solution. But I have to verify it first.

Comment: There is no native support for eager loading with a limit in Laravel. I've created a package for this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Thanks for the tip :) You don't happend to know if it is possible to left/right join using eager?

Comment: Please open a new question for this.